# Преимущества авторизации по токенам и JWT в Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

недавно начал изучать DRF и столкнулся с тем, что не совсем понимаю смысл авторизации по токенам. Для себя я определил, что они используются тогда, когда мы пишем, к примеру, мобильное приложение и у нас нет доступа к CSRF токенам, а какие то ограничения ввести надо. Подскажите, пожалуйста, это имеет место быть или ход мыслей неправильный?
Также вопрос по JWT токенам, если обычные хоть хранятся где-то и по сути служат только для идентификации пользователей, то JWT нигде не хранятся, а также имеют срок жизни, в чем я не вижу вообще никакого смысла в обычных веб или мобильных приложениях, к примеру, форумах, где пользователь практически всегда авторизован. Для чего они нужны?

Comment: А что такое CSRF токены ? и причем тут мобильное приложение, с какой стати ему может быть не доступно что то, что доступно web браузеру

Comment: jwt несут в себе слишком много информации, которая с течением времени может изменится. короткий срок жизни побуждает приложение их менять и тогда же обновляется их содержимое. Далеко не всегда руки доходят до систем отзыва токенов при потенциальной смене их содержимого

Comment: И кстати никто не мешает вам jwt хранить где и как угодно и делать их вечными. jwt это лишь способ кодирования информации в токене. Так же как и например делать не хранимыми не jwt

Comment: @Mike Я так понял, что CSRF токены используются для защиты от атак с помощью cookie и только в браузере, что делает их недоступными в тех же мобильных приложениях на React Native

Comment: мобильному приложению никто не мешает использовать куки и токены в них сохраненные

Comment: @Mike Хорошо, я тогда поищу в этом направлении. А по сравнению с обычным токеном jwt предоставляет какую дополнительную меру безопасности, к примеру, по сравнению с обычным токеном из того же djoser, если токены хранятся в бд? Или его преимущество только в том, что он хранит в себе user_id?

Comment: user_id вам никто не мешает положить и в любой другой токен. Как я сказал выше jwt это лишь способ кодирования. Вы можете любую информацию хранить и в не jwt токенах, разработав свой способ кодирования. И jwt не предоставляет никаких дополнительных мер безопасности. Меры безопасности зависят от того как именно вы используете токены, будь то jwt или не jwt

Comment: Кстати, защита от CSRF обычно выполняется не с помощью кук. Потому как куки как раз и есть то, за счет чего CSRF становятся возможны (с кучей оговорок конечно, если вы точно работаете с CORS)

Comment: Наверное, я все понял, теперь знаю куда копать, спасибо!

Comment: Еще короткий срок жизни и обмен при предъявлении рефреш-токена повышает безопасность за счет уменьшения вероятности перехвата и долговременного использования полученного токена. Но опять же никто не мешает сделать срок жизни и у не jwt токенов

Comment: @Mike Если я правильно понимаю логику, то если я создаю мобильное приложение, в нем есть регистрация и авторизация, то после того как пользователь вошел в систему, то раз в некоторое время (время жизни токена) я должен перевыпускать токен?

Comment: Да, проверяя при этом некие другие данные, идентифициоуещие пользователя. Чаще всего для этого используют рефреш-токен с очень большим или не ограниченным сроком жизни. Но почему именно мобильное приложение в вопросе я не понял, у него нет отличий от web-сайта. Ну кроме несколько большей защищенности от вмешательства из вне

Comment: @Mike Везде, где я сейчас читаю про CSRF защиту пишут, что мобильным приложениям попросту не нужен CSRF, он используется только в браузере, тут получается, что либо нужно делать 2 отдельных API, либо как-то разделять запросы с мобильного и веб приложения.

Comment: @Mike в качестве pet-проекта хочу написать какой-нибудь форум с нативным мобильным приложением и веб сайтом, для Back-end беру DRF, сейчас пытаюсь разобраться в типах авторизации пользователей и их преимуществах, вот поэтому и возникают такие вопросы)

Comment: Мобильному приложению никто не мешает просто соблюдать тот протокол работы который разработан для web-браузера и включает в себя и CSRF защиту. С другой стороны если предприняты все меры по проверке origin (которого кстати от мобильного приложения не будет) то дополнительных мер для защиты от CSRF может и не понадобится. Хотя конечно можно несколько менять поведение api в зависимости от того кто к вам пришел, мобильное или сайт.

Comment: P.S. лично у меня приложение при получении токена сообщает что оно приложение и в самом токене есть поле отвечающее за тип приложения, поэтому остальное api всегда автоматически знает кто перед ним. Это как раз к тому, какую еще полезную информацию можно положить в токен

Comment: Да, я понимаю, что никто не мешает. А если у нас существует авторизация по токенам, нам также нужно будет и csrf передавать, если работаем из веб приложения?

Comment: Ну это смотря где у вас токен передается. Если в заголовке и соответственно берется из памяти приложения, то не надо (при условии, что вы уверены, что сторонний сайт не сможет получить токен). А если он в куках и вы не уверены, что защитились другими способами от вызова api со сторонних сайтов (см. origin и CORS) то нужна (при наличии чувствительных к утечке/подмене данных)

Comment: @Mike Спасибо за ответы)